# Installing .net framework using wine

Tags: wine, nfs, winetricks

I am trying to install .NET frameworks on an Ubuntu system in Wine.

```
wine --version 1.6.2
winetricks --version 20140302
```

The wine is a 32bit version. I get either of two errors:

1. `unable to find a volume for the file extraction, please verify that you have proper permissions.`

   Since this is running inside wine, I don't need `sudo`, so why is it throwing this error (e. g. when `winetricks dotnet20sp1`).
2. `Not enough disk space is available for extraction and installation.`

   I have 20GB free space in my home directory (which should be enough, right?), tried installing on another disk, which is multiple TBs, still giving same error.
   The Linux system is completely NFS, but this shouldn't be a problem I think. Anyone got an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Did you download Net frame work off the site ?

Comment: @Neil I downloaded only if the winetricks workflow told me to download.

Comment: @DavidFoerster This question describes other problems